# What does SKErrorCloudServicePermissionDenied and SKErrorCloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, cloud, storekit

There are two new StoreKit errors that have come up in iOS 9.3. I'm trying to make sure my app handles errors in the best way that it can, so was hoping someone could explain what they mean in terms of when they would be called, how you might handle them, and in what cases they wouldn't be called where they normally would?

According to Apple's documentation:

**SKErrorCloudServicePermissionDenied**
: Indicates that the user has not allowed access to Cloud service information.

**SKErrorCloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed**
: Indicates that the device could not connect to the ne(t)work.

First of all, what is Cloud service? And what does it have to do with StoreKit? When I think of Cloud Service, I think of CloudKit and iCloud. But these technologies, to my knowledge, aren't used in StoreKit. Or if they are, no one told me, and WWDC hasn't explained it either.

How could one turn on/off cloud service, and if it's just iCloud, then would that actually stop an IAP from being processed? I don't think so.

And for the SKErrorCloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed, by the description, that sort of sounds like something that would've been implemented long before iOS 9.3 (checking handling an error such as not being able to connect to the network). Of course, if it's not just 'the network', but rather this unknown CloudService network they're talking about, then maybe that's something different?

Comment: I don't know why Apple doesn't document these things, but it's really annoying.

Comment: Did you get any answer?